# Instead of switching to a theme one by one it ends up on the 'solar' theme and doesn't change. What's the problem?

Tags: javascript, html, web, themes

This is the code -

```
const bodyClassList = document.body.classList;
const bodyClass = document.body.className;
const themes = ["light", "solar", "dark"];

themeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   themes.forEach(theme => {
      bodyClassList.replace(bodyClass, theme);  
   })
   
   theme = document.body.className;
   console.log(theme);
})
```

**Instead of switching to a theme one by one it ends up on the 'solar' theme and doesn't change. What's the problem?**

Comment: could you give a working examplr

Comment: do you want to change the theme with a specific theme when the button is clicked or you want to have some sort of animation (change the themes, first light than solar than dark) when you click the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't fully understand your task, but I thought you needed a switch for several background color classes of the `body` tag.

I made you an example of switching between classes using the `switch` operator, as well as a class index counter from an `themes[...]` array.

Next, I clean up the `classList`:

```
bodyClassList.classList = '';
```

And add the class with the appropriate index:

```
bodyClassList.classList.add(themes[index]);
```

Was such a result necessary?

```js
const bodyClassList = document.body;
const themes = ["light", "solar", "dark"];
const themeBtn = document.querySelector('.themeBtn');
let index = 0;

themeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      index = 1;
      break;
    case 1:
      index = 2;
      break;
    case 2:
      index = 0;
      break;
  } 
  
  bodyClassList.classList = '';
  bodyClassList.classList.add(themes[index]);  
  
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.light {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.solar {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.dark {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button class="themeBtn">theme</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was really confused :D